# Gradually reveal blocks of text within a slide

Tags: ioslides, rpres

Does anyone know of a quick way to gradually reveal text within a slide in ioslide?

The goal would be to not have to repeat the whole block of previous text in order to get a sequence of slides where the amount of text gradually increases, but just use some markdown for it.